# Describing behaviors observed only for certain tasks

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to use a short term to describe behaviors that are observed only for certain tasks. Can I use "task-wise behaviors" or "task-specific behaviors"? Or is there any other better and more formal terms to describe this?

Comment: Googling "task-specific behaviors" finds 110 or so instances of its use. None for of "task-wise behaviors". (That might not help you. Sorry.)

Comment: See [cogsci.se] Good Luck.